# Mongoid 4 (GitHub master) creating documents with duplicate IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, sidekiq

I am running a high traffic test with Sidekiq that creates MongoDB based objects using Mongoid as my driver in a Rails 4 app. The issue I'm seeing is that when a `PlayByPlay` document is supposed to have a unique `game_id`, I see multiple PlayByPlay objects getting created with the same exact game_id. I've enforced the unique constraint on MongoDB as well and this is still happening. Here's my document, it's embedded document, and a glimpse into how I'm creating the documents. The issue is that this is all happening in a threaded environment using Sidekiq, and I'm not sure if there is a way to work around it. My write concern is set to `1` in `mongoid.yml` and it looks like the `safe` option was removed in master as was `persist_in_safe_mode`. Code below -- any suggestions on how to properly work this would be appreciated. This is not a replica set, it's a single MongoDB server performing all read/write requests at this time.

```
module MLB
    class Play
        include Mongoid::Document
        include Mongoid::Timestamps

        embedded_in :play_by_play

        field :batter#, type: Hash
        field :next_batter#, type: Hash
        field :pitchers#, type: Array
        field :pitches#, type: Array
        field :fielders#, type: Array
        field :narrative, type: String
        field :seq_id, type: Integer
        field :inning, type: Integer
        field :outs
        field :no_play
        field :home_team_score
        field :away_team_score
    end
    class PlayByPlay 
        include Mongoid::Document
        include Mongoid::Timestamps

        embeds_many :plays, cascade_callbacks: true
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :plays

        field   :sport
        field :datetime, type: DateTime
        field :gamedate, type: DateTime
        field :game_id
        field :home_team_id
        field :away_team_id
        field :home_team_score
        field :away_team_score
        field :season_year
        field :season_type
        field :location
        field :status
        field :home_team_abbr
        field :away_team_abbr
        field :hp_umpire
        field :fb_umpire
        field :sb_umpire
        field :tb_umpire

        index({game_id: 1})
        index({away_team_id: 1})
        index({home_team_id: 1})
        index({season_type: 1})
        index({season_year: 1})

        index({"plays.seq_id" => 1}, {unique: true, drop_dups: true})
        #validates 'play.seq_id', uniqueness: true
        validates :game_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true
        validates :home_team_id, presence: true
        validates :away_team_id, presence: true
        validates :gamedate, presence: true
        validates :datetime, presence: true
        validates :season_type, presence: true
        validates :season_year, presence: true

        def self.parse!(entry)
            @document = Nokogiri::XML(entry.data)
            xslt = Nokogiri::XSLT(File.read("#{$XSLT_PATH}/mlb_pbp.xslt"))
            transform = xslt.apply_to(@document)
            json_document = JSON.parse(transform)

            obj = find_or_create_by(game_id: json_document['game_id'])
            obj.sport                   = json_document['sport']
            obj.home_team_id        = json_document['home_team_id']
            obj.away_team_id        = json_document['away_team_id']
            obj.home_team_score = json_document['home_team_score']
            obj.away_team_score = json_document['away_team_score']
            obj.season_type         = json_document['season_type']
            obj.season_year         = json_document['season_year']
            obj.location                = json_document['location']
          obj.datetime              =   DateTime.strptime(json_document['datetime'], "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")
            obj.gamedate                = DateTime.strptime(json_document['game_date'], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p")
            obj.status                  = json_document['status']
            obj.home_team_abbr  = json_document['home_team_abbr']
            obj.away_team_abbr  = json_document['away_team_abbr']
            obj.hp_umpire           = json_document['hp_umpire']
            obj.fb_umpire           = json_document['fb_umpire']
            obj.sb_umpire           = json_document['sb_umpire']
            obj.tb_umpire           = json_document['tb_umpire']
            p=obj.plays.build(seq_id: json_document['seq_id'])
            p.batter            =   json_document['batter']
            p.next_batter = json_document['next_batter'] if json_document['next_batter'].present? && json_document['next_batter'].keys.count >= 1
            p.pitchers      = json_document['pitchers'] if json_document['pitchers'].present? && json_document['pitchers'].count >= 1
            p.pitches       =   json_document['pitches'] if json_document['pitches'].present? && json_document['pitches'].count >= 1
            p.fielders      = json_document['fielders'] if json_document['fielders'].present? && json_document['fielders'].count >= 1
            p.narrative     =   json_document['narrative']
            p.seq_id            = json_document['seq_id']
            p.inning            = json_document['inning']
            p.outs              = json_document['outs']
            p.no_play       =   json_document['no_play']
            p.home_team_score = json_document['home_team_score']
            p.away_team_score = json_document['away_team_score']

            obj.save
        end

    end
end
```

** NOTE **

This problem goes away if I limit sidekiq to 1 worker, which obviously in the real world I'd never do.

Answer (score 3):

You already have an index on `game_id`, why not making it unique? that way the db will not allow a duplicate entry, even if mongoid fails to do the validation correctly (**@vidaica**'s answer describes how mongoid could fail to validate the uniqueness).

Try adding a unique index
`index({"game_id" => 1}, {unique: true})`
and then
`rake db:mongoid:create_indexes`

to create them in mongo (please make sure that it is created from a mongo shell).

After that, mongodb should not persist any records with duplicate `game_id` and you'll have to do on the ruby layer is to handle the insert errors that you'll receive from mongodb.

Answer (score 2):

This is because many threads inserting objects with the same game_id. Let me paraphrase it.

For example, you have two sidekiq threads t1 and t2. They run in parallel. Assuming you have a document with `game_id 1` and it has not been inserted into the database.

1. t1 enters `parse` method, it sees no document in the database with `game_id 1`, it creates a document with `game_id 1` and continues to populate other data, but it has not saved the document.
2. t2 enters `parse` method, it sees no document in the database with `game_id 1` because at this point t1 has not saved the document. t2 creates a document with the same `game_id 1`.
3. t1 save the document
4. t2 save the document

The result: you have two documents with the same `game_id 1`.

To prevent this you can use a Mutex to serialize the access of the parsing code. To know how to use a Mutex, read this: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Mutex.html

Comment: Another solution would be to perform the tasks after a given time. `MyWorker.perform_in(5.seconds, 1, 2, 3)` it might not be acceptable though.

Comment: Mutex pretty much puts horizontal scalability of the workers out of the question, ideally you'd need something that locks across a cluster

Comment: @bbozo Mutex will not work in this case if the OP runs sidekiq threads on many different computers. But it works if the OP runs them only on one computer. If the OP runs sidekiq threads on many computers, he may need another solution.

Comment: Hopefully that's what I said :) Mutex would work as long as there's one process running on one computer, afaik it breaks if you run another sidekiq process on same computer and it definitely breaks if you run sidekiq processes on different computers. Considering the OP worries about performance under high load it would probably not be a good call to exclude horizontal scalability out of the picture by design. The solution is somewhere at the mongo level

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, you will want to solve this on the database level because you will almost certainly do a worst job of implementing unique constraints then what mongo people did.

Assuming you will want to shard one day or consider mongo due to its horizontal scalability features (you're doing high volume testing so I assume this is something you don't want to rule out by design), there may be no reliable way to do this (see [Ramifications of working with a mongodb cluster](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2623-ramifications-of-working-with-a-mongodb-cluster/) and [sharding concepts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding/)):

> Suppose we were sharding on email and wanted to have a unique index on username. This is not possible to enforce with a cluster.

However, if you're sharding on `game_id` or you're not considering sharding at all then setting a unique index on `game_id` should prevent double records (see **@xlembouras** answer).

However, that answer may not prevent exceptions when this index is violated due to race conditions so be sure to rescue that exception and perform an update instead of create in the rescue block (possibly by playing with [@new_record (click 'Show source')](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-new_record-3F), will try to find time to give you exact code).

**UPDATE, short fast answer**

```
begin
  a = Album.new(name: 'foo', game_id: 3)
  a.save
rescue
  a.id = id_of_the_object_with_same_id_already_in_db
  a.instance_variable_set('@new_record', false)
  a.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

@vidaica's answer is helpful. If you were fetching and incrementing an ID from memory or a database, it might solve your problem.

However, your `game_id` is not being generated in `parse`, it is being passed into `parse` via the `entry` JSON object.

How / where is your `game_id` being generated?

Comment: In this case I guess it's not that important where game_id originates from. It may be a legitimate case for several documents/entries to have the same game_id but different plays. If a document with a duplicate game_id is processed, he still calls find_or_create_by, so without concurrency described by @vidaica he'd never get two records with the same game_id.

Comment: If, however, two documents also should never have the same game_id, then an additional problem is in potential concurrency issues when async-calling the worker's functions. But the fact that there is find_or_create_by() and still there is this problem with duplicate game_ids, clearly indicates that at least the concurrency problem from vidaica answer is present. May be that's not the only problem, but it's the first to address.

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach is to change the last line of `#parse` to:

```
obj.save if where(game_id: obj.game_id).count == 0
```

Or if you hand to handle it somehow:

```
if where(game_id: obj.game_id).count == 0
  # handle it here
end
```

Note however that this still leaves possibilities for duplicates.

Comment: This solution can't eliminate documents with the same game_id from being inserted. Because the obj.save takes time and by the time it finishes saving, other threads may reach to the checking code and still see no existing document with the same game_id and then insert other documents with the same game_id

Comment: It also doesn't solve race condition cases where both threads perform count at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do an upsert instead of an insert:

```
obj = new(game_id: json_document['game_id'])
obj.upsert
```